# "Handmade" TabView for Android

Tags: android, tabs, tabbar

I'm not really fascinated by TabView in Android.

So I've got a crazy idea how to do a "handmade"-almost-TabView.

Before I start to implement it, I decide to ask you, if this idea too bad, what are negative or positive sides of it.

- Assume the whole application should
  include tabbar.
- The Layout of every activity will
  get as tabbar for example in its
  layout a horizonatally oriented
  linear layout with tabs.
- Selected tab identificator will be a static
  variable and will just affect, which
  tab-icon should be selected.
- For complicated uses (if it desired to save activities history within each tab) activitygroups will be used. each activity group will be associated with corresponding tab.

Thank you in advance for every criticism and suggestions.

Mur

Ps.
I hope, it's not a wrong place for discussion. But if, just suggest, where would it be to discuss this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi
You can refer to this application demo for tabwidget

http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=6